# all letters lowercase, except the first word in a sentence

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string

```
s = "Test TEst TEST. Test. TEST. TEST. Test test test."
```

I need to make the result something like this

```
s = "Test test test. Test. Test. Test. Test test test."
```

How I can do this on ruby ?

thx.

Comment: `s.gsub(/\S[^.]+\./, &:capitalize)`

Comment: Did you [search this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+title+case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.gsub(/\w[^.]*/, &:capitalize)
# => "Test test test. Test. Test. Test. Test test test."
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s =  "Test TEst TEST. Test. TEST. TEST. Test test test."
p s.split('. ').map(&:capitalize).join('. ')
#=> "Test test test. Test. Test. Test. Test test test."
```